# In WordPress, when using query_posts(), why does pagination not work?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

This is the code in index.php. When I click "Older Posts", it still shows the first page content. Only the default loop works with pagination.

```
    <?php 
    query_posts('showposts=10');
    query_posts("cat=2");
    if( have_posts() ):

        while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part('content',get_post_format()); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php next_posts_link('« Older Posts'); ?>
            <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts »'); ?>

    <?php endif;
        wp_reset_query();   
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) is not recommended for use this way, as it will overwrite the main query, and specific to your case, [does not support pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#pagination) by default. You should probably use [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) or use the [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) object.

If you must use `query_posts()`, then there is an explanation on the link above on how to add the `paged` parameter to a query.

Here's the same code, but using `get_posts()`.

```
<?php 
$args = array('numberposts' => 10, 'category' => 2);
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($posts as $post) {   
    // Use the $post object here in your content template
    <?php get_template_part('content',get_post_format()); ?>
}
<?php next_posts_link('« Older Posts'); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts »'); ?>
```